# WebRTC : STUN-based connexions suddenly stopped working

Tags: webrtc, stun, ice-protocol

We are building a little web-application based on WebRTC. Everything was fine as we could connect pretty much everyone either by STUN or TURN.

During the past weeks, we suddenly stopped getting success from all connections based on STUN (so pretty much every connections). We didn't touch anything, it just stopped working. That is weird because "host" (local) or "relay" (TURN) work fine so I don't think it has to do with the code managing the WebRTC call.

I'm doing the tests by selecting only the ICE candidates marked as "srflx" (STUN) to pass the ICE gathering. I tested "host"-only and "relay"-only with success.

Everything seems fine and "onaddstream" is even fired, but I just seem to not get any valid remote stream to display.

We are using some Xirsys ICE servers and a few public google stun servers. I already tried playing with the server list I give to the API, but the problem seems linked to the STUN itself, not the servers (this, or every STUN server I give isn't working ...)

I was wondering if something major changed in the WebRTC API recently or if I am even able to force-STUN on the same computer (would be weird as I can force-TURN).

Comment: You can use Wireshark for monitoring network packets to verify that if your stun requests are leaving your device and if there are any response coming to your device from stun server but your program is not picking it up. This will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the exact same issue.